# Semidirect products of groups (and its relation to the coproduct)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose I have two groups $G,H$ and a homomorphism $H\rightarrow\text{Aut}(N)$. Suppose further that I have another group $T$ and two maps: $f_G : G\rightarrow\text{Aut}(T)$ and $f_H : H\rightarrow\text{Aut}(T)$.

Does this induce a map $f : G\rtimes H\rightarrow\text{Aut}(T)$ that restricts to $f_G,f_H$ on $G$ and $H$?

The context for this question is as follows. Let $N$ be an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_d]$. Then the multiplicative group $(\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_d]/N)^*$ acts on its additive group $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_d]/N$ by multiplication. Thus, we may form the semidirect product $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_d]/N\rtimes (\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_d]/N)^*$. Clearly the first factor acts on $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_d]/N$ by translation, and the second factor acts on $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_d]/N$ as mentioned before by multiplication, thus yielding maps
$$\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_d]/N\rightarrow\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_d]/N),\qquad\text{and}\qquad (\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_d]/N)^*\rightarrow\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_d]/N).$$
(here by Aut I mean automorphism groups of the set)

Gabriel Berger in section 2.3 of his paper "[Fake Congruence Modular Curves and Subgroups of the Modular Group](http://pdn.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=MiamiImageURL&_cid=272332&_user=209810&_pii=S0021869398976785&_check=y&_origin=article&_zone=toolbar&_coverDate=1999--01&view=c&originContentFamily=serial&wchp=dGLzVBA-zSkWA&md5=2dd8e0d714d264cf7c4acdd9ec58ac84&pid=1-s2.0-S0021869398976785-main.pdf)" says that this induces an action of $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_d]/N\rtimes (\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_d]/N)^*$ on $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_d]/N$ (as a set). However, I don't see how this action can work (his description of the action doesn't seem to be a legit action).

In other words, our $G$ is the additive group of $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_d]/N$, and $H$ is the multiplicative group of that ring. Then multiplication in the semidirect product is done as follows: $(g_1,h_1)(g_2,h_2) = (g_1 + h_1g_2, h_1h_2)$ (actually his multiplication I think is the opposite of this, but neither multiplication works to make the action that he describes a legit group action).

Now take $t\in\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_d]/N$, and consider the action that he describes (taken as a right-action): $t.(g,h) = (t+g)h$.

Now consider: $t.(g_1,h_1)(g_2,h_2)$.

First, $t.((g_1,h_1)(g_2,h_2)) = t.(g_1+h_1g_2, h_1h_2) = (t+g_1+h_1g_2)h_1h_2 = th_1h_2 + g_1h_1h_2 + h_1^2h_2g_2$

On the other hand, $(t.(g_1,h_1))(g_2,h_2) = ((t+g_1)h_1 + g_2)h_2 = th_1h_2 + g_1h_1h_2 + g_2h_2$

Which are clearly not the same. Pretending that the action is a left-action still doesn't fix things.

Comment: I'm actually more interested in the special case which I wrote above as the "context" for the first question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all Berger claims is that the semidirect product $\mathbf{Z}[\zeta_{d}] \rtimes \mathbf{Z}[\zeta_{d}]^{*}$ *acts on the set* $\mathbf{Z}[\zeta_{d}]$. The element $(a,b) \in \mathbf{Z}[\zeta_{d}] \rtimes \mathbf{Z}[\zeta_{d}]^{*}$ acts on $x \in \mathbf{Z}[\zeta_{d}]$ by $x \mapsto b x + a$. It seems to me that this is quite clearly spelled out by Berger, which works in a slightly more general setting.

Comment: Ahhhh, see what he wrote was that $t(x[\gamma]) = (t+x)[\gamma]$ (ie, first add, then multiply), whereas the action you gave was $t(x[\gamma]) = (t\gamma + x)$ (first multiply, then add).

Comment: thanks!

I can't believe I didn't think to check that. My intuition for semidirect products is terrible.

Comment: @oxeimon you're welcome!